# SMS with full company name and company logo

Tags: android, twilio, sms, bulksms

Android : we receive messages from many companies with their company name and brand logo in the sms. I have started a small firm and am looking to send sms to my clients but with company full name and brand logo.

What I have set up.
In India we have a 6 digit sender code, I have got this, but this does not give company logo or full company name.

Can anyone please assist on how it is can be achieved.

Attached screen shot for reference.

[image]

Comment: I think you're looking for google's [verified sms](https://developers.google.com/business-communications/verified-sms)?

Answer (score 0):

Pawel suggested that this is Google's Verified SMS. I note that you tagged this question "twilio", so let me answer from that perspective. Twilio [supports Verified SMS](https://www.twilio.com/blog/verified-sms-helps-promote-trust) but you need to [sign up to access it here](https://ahoy.twilio.com/verified-sms?_ga=2.204971029.40145370.1645397018-793170186.1633388929).